# Checkbox not firing

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/raficsaza/mgukxouj/

The problem is I cannot use the checkbox, it's stuck on false value and not moving at all.
Can I go through the "input" tag, because I cannot remove it...

```
<div class="toggler">
        <input class="toggler-checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The isOK field is required." id="isOK" name="isOK" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="isOK" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <label class="toggler-label" for="mytoggler">
            <span class="toggler-inner"></span>
            <span class="toggler-switch"></span>
        </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Does [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/x1wbqmdz/) work with your application?

Comment: Nope still grey... Is any possible solutions to trigger label over input?

Answer (score 1):

The adjacent sibling selector isn't working because you have a hidden input after the checkbox and before the label. Change your HTML to move it to before like so:

```
<input name="isOK" type="hidden" value="false" />
<input class="toggler-checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The isOK field is required." id="isOK" name="isOK" type="checkbox" checked />
```

As an aside, you shouldn't use the same `name` attribute for both the checkbox and hidden input. You should also use the `checked` attribute rather than `value="true"` if you want the checkbox to be checked by default.

Second, your label isn't pointing to your checkbox, you need to change the `for` attribute to match the checkbox's ID:

```
<label class="toggler-label" for="isOK">
```

If you can't move/delete the hidden input, you can still get to the label by changing your CSS:

```
.toggler-checkbox:checked + input + .toggler-label .toggler-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.toggler-checkbox:checked + input + .toggler-label .toggler-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgukxouj/8/)

Comment: Sorry about for tag (my mistake)... But I cannot move it cause I'm using MVC and this is generated automatically. That's why I'm trying to find a way to jump over hiddden input <input name="isOK" type="hidden" value="false" />    -   if you just remove this line should work perfectly, but I need it...

Comment: @Rafaelo I've updated my answer and fiddle to address the issue of not being able to change the hidden input.